# Is Sql Server Express edition 2005 64 bit supported on Windows Server 2008 64 bit?

Tags: sql-server-2005, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

Couldn't find any reference to this online.
Does any one know?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will be...

Edit: From AdaTheDev's link

> Note: SQL Server 2008 Express
>   includes both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   versions. SQLEXPR32_x86 is a smaller
>   package that can be used to install
>   SQL Server 2008 Express onto only
>   32-bit operating systems. SQLEXPR_x86
>   is the same product but supports
>   installation onto both 32-bit and
>   64-bit (WoW) operating systems.
>   **SQLEXPR_x64 is a native 64-bit SQL
>   Server 2008 Express and supports
>   installation onto only 64-bit
>   operating systems.** There is no other
>   difference between these packages.

Comment: Thanks, but what relationship SQLEXPR_x86 or SQLEXPR_x64 have
with SQL EXPRESS 2005 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=31711d5d-725c-4afa-9d65-e4465cdff1e7&displaylang=en#Requirements), it doesn't say 2005 Express is supported on Windows Server 2008:

> Supported Operating Systems: Windows
>   2000 Service Pack 4; Windows Server
>   2003 Service Pack 1; Windows Vista;
>   Windows XP Service Pack 2

Whereas for SQL Server 2008 Express [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=58ce885d-508b-45c8-9fd3-118edd8e6fff&displaylang=en#Requirements) it does support Windows 2008:

> Supported Operating Systems: Windows
>   Server 2003 Service Pack 2; Windows
>   Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows
>   Vista Service Pack 1; Windows XP
>   Service Pack 2; Windows XP Service
>   Pack 3

If you have a look at [this article](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/04/18/how-to-install-sql-server-2005-on-windows-server-2008/), it goes over some issues/resolutions when trying to install SQL Server 2005 on Windows 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is it officially supported by Microsoft but I can confirm it's working with no problems.